# Draw a triangle in HTML canvas based on three given lenths

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I'm trying to create a function that draws a triangle in the middle of an HTML canvas based on three given lengths, I thought this would be an easy intro to HTML canvas, I was wrong.

Here's where I have so far, but the sides aren't rendering properly:

```
function drawTriangle(sideOne, sideTwo, sideThree) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('triangle-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var cx = canvas.width / 2;
    var cy = canvas.height / 4;

    var sideOneHeight = sideOne * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);
    var sideTwoHeight = sideTwo * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx, cy);
    ctx.lineTo(cx + 50, cy + sideOneHeight);
    ctx.lineTo(cx - 50, cy + sideTwoHeight);
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you expect it to work? Did you put to paper the equations of the two circles that have to intersect?

Comment: @LutzL Didn't even know about the circles intersecting bit. This was just meant to be an intro but I'm probably just not going to grasp it. Your solution does work tho!!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `Ax=0, Ay=0`, set `Bx=R3, By=0`. Then the third point satisfies two circle equations

```
(Cx-Ax)² + (Cy-Ay)² = R2²
(Cx-Bx)² + (Cy-By)² = R1²
```

which given the chosen coordinates reduce to

```
Cx² + Cy² = R2²
(Cx-R3)² + Cy² = R1²
```

and in the difference

```
 2*Cx*R3 = R2²+R3²-R1²
```

which allows to compute `Cx` and from that `Cy`.

In code it looks like this:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById('triangle-canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var R1=120, R2=140, R3=90;
    var Ax=0, Ay=0;
    var Bx=R3, By=0;
    var Cx=(R2*R1+R3*R3-R1*R1)/(2*R3);
    var Cy=Math.sqrt(R2*R2-Cx*Cx);

    var Ox = canvas.width / 2 - Bx/2;
    var Oy = canvas.height / 2 + Cy/2;

 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(Ox+Ax, Oy-Ay);
    ctx.lineTo(Ox+Bx, Oy-By);
    ctx.lineTo(Ox+Cx, Oy-Cy);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle="gold"; ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.stroke(); ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id='triangle-canvas' height=200 width=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "20px Times New Roman";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
var canvasSize = [parseInt(c.width), parseInt(c.height)];
var _side_1 = 5, _side_2 = 3, _side_3 = 4; //All values are taken assuming as centimeter unit.
var factor = 37.7952755906;
var sides = [_side_1, _side_2, _side_3];
sides.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
var halfPerimeter = (_side_1 + _side_2 + _side_3) / 2;
var area = Math.sqrt(halfPerimeter * (halfPerimeter - _side_1) * (halfPerimeter - _side_2) * (halfPerimeter - _side_3));
var height = ((2 * area) / sides[2]).toPrecision(5);
var slopeOfBase = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sides[0], 2) - Math.pow(height, 2));
   
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.setLineDash([]);
ctx.moveTo((canvasSize[0]/2 - 0.5 * sides[2] * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.lineTo((canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.fillText("c = " + sides[2] + " cm",(canvasSize[0]/2 - 0.5 * sides[2] * factor + canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor) / 2,(canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor + canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor) / 2 + 15);
ctx.lineTo((canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 - 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.fillText("b = " + sides[0] + " cm",(canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor + canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor) / 2 + 50,(canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor + canvasSize[1]/2 - 0.5 * height * factor) / 2);
ctx.lineTo((canvasSize[0]/2 - 0.5 * sides[2] * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.fillText("a = " + sides[1] + " cm",(canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor + canvasSize[0]/2 - 0.5 * sides[2] * factor) / 2 - 50,(canvasSize[1]/2 - 0.5 * height * factor + canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor) / 2);
ctx.stroke();
    
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.setLineDash([5]);
ctx.moveTo((canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 - 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.lineTo((canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor), (canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor));
ctx.fillText("h = " + height + " cm",(canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor + canvasSize[0]/2 + 0.5 * sides[2] * factor - slopeOfBase * factor) / 2,(canvasSize[1]/2 - 0.5 * height * factor + canvasSize[1]/2 + 0.5 * height * factor) / 2 + 20);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
```