# How to draw a triangle on three sides JS?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I will have 3 inputs and a button. When you click on this button you should draw a triangle in which the lengths of 3 sides are equal to the values in the inputs. How to organize it? I found this:

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(30, 20);
context.lineTo(some_value1,some_value2);
context.lineTo(some_value3,some_value4);
context.closePath();
```

But this method is suitable for drawing, on two sides.
I hope now I have described the problem in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to compute cartesian coordinates of each point first.

Comment: Also `context.lineTo` method has two parameters - `x` and `y` coordinates.

Comment: @MartinAdámek well, can you know any method?

Comment: What parameters do you have from user? Just lengths of all 3 sides?

Comment: @MartinAdámek yes. Just lengths of all 3 sides. Edit `lineTo`

Comment: You did not describe a problem, but a request. This is not your code and you are asking people to suggest how to modify it.

Comment: @Boaz no, I just ask how to compute cartesian coordinates of each point first

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич Is this your code? Have you made any effort to solve the issue on your own?

Comment: @Boaz, yes. It is my code. I have  made any effort to solve the issue on your own

Comment: Honestly this is more of a math question. Look up "how to construct a triangle given three sides" for the method, then you just need to implement it in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a triangle in HTML canvas based on three given lenths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063695/draw-a-triangle-in-html-canvas-based-on-three-given-lenths)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to compute cartesian coordinates of each point first. You can set the first point to `[0, 0]`, and the second will be at `[x1, 0]` where `x1` is length of first line. Third point needs to be calculated, take a look here how this can be done:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543961/determine-third-point-of-triangle-when-two-points-and-all-sides-are-known

```js
// hardcoded, but you would get those from user
var AB = 40;
var BC = 50;
var AC = 30;

var A = [0, 0]; // starting coordinates
var B = [0, AB];
var C = [];

// calculate third point
C[1] = (AB * AB + AC * AC - BC * BC) / (2 * AB);
C[0] = Math.sqrt(AC * AC - C[1] * C[1]);
console.log(A, B, C);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(A[0], A[1]);
ctx.lineTo(B[0], B[1]);
ctx.lineTo(C[0], C[1]);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!