# Drawing a triangle in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to draw some triangles in a canvas procedurally (eventually adding some animation and other effects). I've managed to get some simple shapes into the canvas but fo some reason cannot draw triangles for some reason. I've been using some code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805017/how-to-draw-triangle-programmatically-on-canvas-in-javascript) but so far it doesn't work.

**HTML**

There's more, but for simplicity I've left out the parts that aren't used at all. I'm using Bootstrap. That script path is a valid path as well.

```js
function triangles() {
    let left = document.getElementById("left")
    let ctx = left.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 100);
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.stroke();
}

triangles()
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid #A2A2A2;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-vh-100">
    <div class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-2">
            <canvas id="left"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">

        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <canvas id="right"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this gives me a completely blank canvas. As said previously, I have played around with other ways of drawing to the canvas such as the [`fillRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/canvasrenderingcontext2d/fillrect) function and can draw properly.

Any advice is probably helpful thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just moving around. To draw shapes, use `lineTo`.

```js
let left = document.getElementById("left")
let ctx = left.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.lineWidth = 4;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="left"></canvas>
```